# How to resolve absolute uri error when I am just using jsp neither using servlet nor any framwork

Tags: java, jsp, taglib

When I am using this controller code :

```
public class BuisnessController {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BuisnessController.class);

    public void addbuisnessimage(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, String bpath) {
        String ret = ""; // For User Registration and File upload code

        String business = "";
        String subbuisn = "";
        String image_file = "";

        try {
            if (request.getContentType().indexOf("multipart/form-data") != -1) {
                List list = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory())
                    .parseRequest(request);
                java.util.Iterator it = list.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    FileItem fl = (FileItem) it.next();
                    if (fl.isFormField()) {
                        String fname = fl.getFieldName();
                        String fval = fl.getString();
                        if (fname.equalsIgnoreCase("business")) {
                            business = fval;
                        } else if (fname.equalsIgnoreCase("image_file")) {
                            image_file = fval;
                        } else if (fname.equalsIgnoreCase("subbuisn")) {
                            subbuisn = fval;
                        }
                    } else {
                        String filename = fl.getName();
                        File file = new File(bpath,"images");
                        file.mkdirs();
                        String basepath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                        long t = 0;
                        String ext = "error";
                        try {
                            t = new java.util.Date().getTime();
                            int l = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
                            ext = filename.substring(l, filename.length());
                            String fpath = basepath + "/" + t + ext;

                            File f = new File(fpath);
                            fl.write(f);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        BuisnessImageDTO adminRoleDTO2 = new BuisnessImageDTO();
                        adminRoleDTO2.setBusiness(business);
                        adminRoleDTO2.setSubbuisn(subbuisn);
                        adminRoleDTO2.setImage_file(image_file);

                        if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("error")) {
                            adminRoleDTO2.setImage_file("NA");
                        } else {
                            adminRoleDTO2.setImage_file(+t + ext);
                        }

                        ret = new BuisnessService().addbuisnessimage(adminRoleDTO2);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (ret.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                request.getRequestDispatcher("buisness-add.jsp").forward(request, response);
            } else {

                request.getRequestDispatcher("buisness-add.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Data Missing", e);
            logger.warn("This is a warning message");
            logger.trace("This message will not be logged since log level is set as DEBUG");

            try {
                request.getRequestDispatcher("buisness-add.jsp").forward(request, response);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                logger.error("IOEXception occured:", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

on my local Tomcat it work properly, but when I deploy my website on server it gives absolute path error for every folder. Even, I arn't able to fetch image form database. It only show the image id like 12356.jsp. I am using javax.servlet.jsp.jstl 1.2.1 jar

Here my xml code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>NewAuthentication</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/AppErrorHandler</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/AppErrorHandler</location>
    </error-page>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4j-config</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>100</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.haani.atp.group.listener.MyListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Please give me suggestion because it is my first time to deploy any websites.

Comment: What you mean "when i deployed my website on server"?

Comment: means when i am using tomcat as a local server web project working is proper. but when i use cpanal as host when i deployed my project on it. when it show http status 500 absolute path error

Comment: @AnkitaChourasiya could you also paste the stacktrace?

Comment: what do u mean by stacktrace

Comment: @AnkitaChourasiya see http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_stack_trace.html what a java stacktrace is

Comment: yesm i know stacktrace is determine the error stack but i put this exception in controller u can see.

Comment: If you want help from SO, then find a way that prints the stacktrace into the browser window and not into a log-file. The community has no access to them and the reason for this error is individual from a individual project.

Comment: when i login in my login panal its done but after login when i click on any page it show http status 500 - the absolute uri http //java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core can not be resolved in either web.xml or jar file deploye with this appliction this error while i am not create servlet just using it.

Comment: @AnkitaChourasiya A jsp file will be converted into a servlet. Maybe your service provider doesn't allow to access to this library (I don't believe it) or you haven't imported into into your jsp files. Have you tried Google to see how you can declare thise library into a web.xml?

Comment: is there any one to solve my issue